# VueJS: How to determinate the "from" route, when route in URL is directly entered in browser?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, routes, vue-router

I have a Vue application and a few routes (let's refer to them as "*homepage*", "*first_route*" and "*second_route*"). Before loading the component for the "*first_route*" route, I want to check from where the user comes from.

There are two options:

- there is a menu in the app and when user clicks in the menu, he will try to access to the corresponding clicked route (imagine this as a simple menu with items like "*Dashboard*", "*About Us*", "*Contact*" pages, just in my case will be "*First Route Page*", "*Second Route Page*" and I will also have the route "/" in this menu, which is the "*HomePage*" of my application);
- while user is on a certain route, he can refresh the browser, which will load his current route again **OR** while he is on a different site (google for example) he can try to directly open the route like "www.mypage.com/first_route"

In general, the idea is:

- if the user comes from the current application (internal - if he clicks in it)
- if the user comes from some external site or if he refresh the page

I'm posting my code below and I'm having issue in forming the **if condition** in the block below:

```
    export default new Router({
        mode: 'history',
        routes: [
            {
                path: "/",
                component: HomePage
            },
            {
                path: "/first_route",
                component: FirstRoutePage,
                beforeEnter (to, from, next) {
                    if (check where the route comes from)
                        // do something if the route comes from page refresh 
                        // or if user directly entered "/first_route" from external site
                    } else {                                     
                        // do something else if the route comes as a result of 
                        // a user click from another route (internal, from the menu)
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                path: "/second_route",
                component: SecondRoutePage
            }
]
```

What I tried is to check:

```
beforeEnter (to, from, next) {
    if (to.path == from.path)
        // do something if the route comes from page refresh 
        // or if user directly entered "/first_route" from external site
    } else {                                     
        // do something else if the route comes as a result of 
        // a user click from another route (internal, from the menu)
    }
}
```

But this covers only the case when user refreshes the browser. The case when user enters directly the full URL into the browser is not covered with this solution.

**The main problem is**: when user enters directly the full URL into the browser, the value which is recognized for the from route for `from.path` is "/". If we are in the "HomePage" (which route is "/" and if user clicks on the menu and chooses the "*/first_route*" page) then we will have the same condition to be true.

In the both cases the `from` and `to` routes are identical. And this is the contradictory thing: in the first case we are coming from the external site and in the second case we are coming from the "/" route (HomePage) but in the both cases the same condition `(from.path == "/" && to.path == "/first_route")` is true, so I can not determinate which of the main two scenarios (from above) was hit.

Answer (score 0):

you could try do this in your created() method.

```
if (this.$route.params.id)
        // do something if the route comes from page refresh 
        // or if user directly entered "/first_route" from external site
    } else {                                     
        // do something else if the route comes as a result of 
        // a user click from another route (internal, from the menu)
    }
```

and in your router just set the id.

```
{
      path: '/example/:id/',
      name: 'example',
      component: () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "about" */ './components/example.vue')
    }
```

Comment: will this also require: when clicking on the menu (internally) in my app, in the clicked routes (in the menu) that I will have to add an "ids" for each route?

Comment: well yeah, but if you want just the name of the route you can get it with `this.$route.path`